# How to execute a UNIX command in Python script

Tags: python, unix

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import shutil
import commands
import time
import copy

name = 'test'

echo name
```

I have a simple python scripts like the above. When I attempt to execute it I get a syntax error  when trying to output the name variable.

Comment: You should at least specify the exact error message you're obtaining.

Comment: Why did you expect a generic unix command (`echo`) to be supported just like that in Python as if it was a recognized Python statement?

Comment: @C2H5OH It just yields a generic “syntax error”, as `echo` is not a keyword and it expects something else to happen after a possible variable name (for example an assignment).

Comment: @poke: Thanks, I already knew that.  I was only trying to improve the OP's manners when asking questions.

Comment: @C2H5OH Already thought you did, but to be fair, *“syntax error”* is as exact as possible in this case ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use UNIX commands in your Python script as if they were Python code, `echo name` is causing a syntax error because `echo` is not a built-in statement or function in Python.  Instead, use `print name`.

To run UNIX commands you will need to create a subprocess that runs the command.  The simplest way to do this is using [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system), but the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module is preferable.

Answer (score 10):

you can also use subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['echo', name],
                            stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr = subprocess.PIPE
                        )

(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print out
```

Read: http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/subprocess/